# Nestjs env variable with ClientsModuleOptions

Tags: node.js, tcp, ip, nestjs, nest

I have the following IP and Ports but I want to carry this with environment variables so that they can be edited from there

```js
import { ClientsModuleOptions, Transport } from "@nestjs/microservices"

export const GatewayOptions: ClientsModuleOptions = [
    {
        name: 'MICRO-ADMIN',
        transport: Transport.TCP,
        options: {
            host: '127.20.20.2',
            port: 4000,
        },
    },
    {
        name: 'MICRO-DEV',
        transport: Transport.TCP,
        options: {
            host: '127.30.30.3',
            port: 5000,
        },
    },
];
```

I import this configuration to the module.

```js
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ClientsModule } from '@nestjs/microservices';
import { GatewayOptions } from 'src/utils/gateway/gateway';
import { AuthModule } from './../auth/auth.module';
import { CategoryModule } from './../category/category.module';
import { GameController } from './game.controller';
import { GameService } from './game.service';

@Module({
  imports: [
    AuthModule,
    CategoryModule,
    ClientsModule.register(GatewayOptions)
   ],
  controllers: [GameController],
  providers: [GameService],
  exports: [GameService],
})
export class GameModule {}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use register async to use `ConfigService`

Follow the documentation: https://docs.nestjs.com/microservices/basics#client

```
@Module({
  providers: [
    {
      provide: 'MATH_SERVICE',
      useFactory: (configService: ConfigService) => {
        const mathSvcOptions = configService.getMathSvcOptions();
        return ClientProxyFactory.create(mathSvcOptions);
      },
      inject: [ConfigService],
    }
  ]
  ...
})
```

Here is how you can configure the `ConfigService`: https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/configuration#configuration